# Connect to ActiveDirectory in C# fails

Tags: c#, active-directory

I try to connect to AD in C#

if I connect to the root, it succeeds without throwing error.

```
        try {
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://COMPANYDOMAIN.COM", "username", "password");
            object nativeObject = de.NativeObject;
        } catch(DirectoryServicesCOMException) { }
```

If I connect with another way like below, it throws `the specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.`

```
        try {
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=COMPANYDOMAIN,DC=COM", "username", "password");
            object nativeObject = de.NativeObject;
        } catch(DirectoryServicesCOMException) { }
```

If I connect to sub OU, it throws `the specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.` too

```
        try {
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=KEE2, DC=COMPANYDOMAIN,DC=COM", "username", "password");
            object nativeObject = de.NativeObject;
        } catch(DirectoryServicesCOMException) { }
```

I can use `LDAPADMIN` GUI tool to connect in and see the structure in AD:

```
ROOT
  OU=KEE2
  OU=KEE
  OU=other..
```

What did I do wrongly here?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the syntax used is wrong... it has to be like this... then no error.

`LDAP://companydomain.com/ou=kee2,dc=COMPANYDOMAIN,dc=com`